# Temporarily disable bootstrap during development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on my first big project with Bootstrap, in Ruby on Rails. It sure slows down all the loading. How can I "switch off" Bootstrap so that I'm just viewing basic text as I work on getting my views functional, so that they load faster? In such a way that I can then "switch it back on" when I'm ready for them to look pretty again?

Answer (score 1):

You can comment the files you load in manifest files removing `=` sign.
In `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
 //= require bootstrap
```

change to

```
 // require bootstrap
```

In `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
*= require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min
```

change to

```
* require bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min
```

Answer (score 0):

Commenting the lines marked as `Bootstrap core CSS`, and `Custom styles for this template` in the head, and all the `Bootstrap core Javascript` at the bottom, seems to have greatly sped up my loading.

I had previously commented out all the IE hack lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using bootstrap via a gem (like `bootstrap-rubygem` or `bootstrap-sass`), then another approach would be to load it only on :production and/or :test environments. This way you can stay out of the inconvenience of commenting/commenting out the `require` statements

```
# Gemfile
group :development do
end

group :test, :production do
  gem 'bootstrap-sass' # or whichever bootstrap gem
end
```